# How do I find a boundary for the following complex integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, inequality

I have the following question.

We need to show that $$\left|\int_{|z-1|=1} \frac{e^z}{z+1}dz \right|\leq 2\pi e^2$$

My idea was the following:
I parametrize $|z-1|=1$ with $\gamma(t)=1+e^{it}$ where $t\in [0,2\pi]$. Then

$$\left|\int_{|z-1|=1} \frac{e^z}{z+1}dz \right|\leq \int_{|z-1|=1}\frac{|e^z|}{|z+1|}dz\leq \int_{|z-1|=1}|e^z|~dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\left|e^{1+e^{it}}\right|ie^{it}~dt$$ now substituting $u=e^{it}$ gives me $du=ie^{it}dt$ and thus the integral above is equal to $$\int _1^{e^{2\pi i}}\left|e^{1+u}\right|du=0\leq 2\pi e^2$$

But I'm not sure if this works, could maybe someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $|z-1|=1$, then\begin{align}\left|\frac{e^z}{z+1}\right|&=\left|\frac{e^z}{2+(z-1)}\right|\\&\leqslant\frac{|e^z|}{2-|z-1|}\\&=|e^z|\\&=e^{\operatorname{Re}z}\\&\leqslant e^2,\end{align}and therefore your integral is smaller than or equal to $e^2$ times the length of the circle centered at $1$ with radius $1$. That is, it is smaller than or equal to $2\pi e^2$.

Comment: but does this mean that my way is wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. We have$$\oint_{|z-1|=1}\frac{e^z}{z+1}\,\mathrm dz=\frac{2\pi}e.$$If your approach was correct, it would be equal to $0$.